# C - Split string with repeated delimiter char into 2 substrings

Tags: c, strtok

I'm making a very simple C program that simulates the **export** command, getting an input with fgets().

Input example:

> KEY=VALUE

Has to be converted to:

```
setenv("KEY", "VALUE", 1);
```

That's easy to solve with something similar to this code:

```
key = strtok(aux, "=");
value = strtok(NULL, "=");
```

The problem comes when the user input a value that start with one or several equals `=` characters. For example:

> KEY===VALUE

This should be converted to:

```
setenv("KEY", "==VALUE", 1);
```

But with my current code it is converted to:

```
setenv("KEY", NULL, 1);
```

How I can solve this?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: You have to write your own parser.

Comment: You could just use `strchr` instead of `strtok`

Comment: Can't reproduce. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/913d3de1fdad058a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second `strtok()` should not use `=` as the delimiter. You would only do that if there were another `=` that ended the value. But the value ends at the end of the string. Use an empty delimiter for this part.

```
key = strtok(aux, "=");
value = strtok(NULL, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtok` is probably overkill (and non-reentrant) when it's just one token. This will do,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *key, *equals, *value;
    if(argc != 2 || !(equals = strchr(key = argv[1], '=')))
       return fprintf(stderr, "KEY=VALUE\n"), EXIT_FAILURE;
    value = equals + 1;
    *equals = '\0';
    printf("key: <%s>; value: <%s>.\n", key, value);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Although `strtok` is probably easier to read. One may try `strsep`, but it is GNU C.